# computed property to collect hasMany data

Tags: ember.js

A `route` hasMany `departuredates`. I'd like to create a computed property which collects the `value` attribute of all `departuredates` and returns a string which comma separates them and adds the end date (which is `departuredate.value` + `route.duration`) of each.

Examples:

- "01.01.2015 - 05.01.2015"
- "02.03.2016 - 12.03.2016, 02.04.2016 - 12.04.2016"

How can I do this? And is `departuredates.@each.value` the correct property to use?

**app/route/model.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  duration: DS.attr('number'),
  departuredates: DS.hasMany('departuredate', { async: true }),

  departuredateText: Ember.computed('departuredates.@each.value', function() {
    // ???
  })
});
```

**app/departuredate/model.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  value: DS.attr('date')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but something like this should work:

```
departuredateText: Ember.computed('duration', 'departuredates.@each.value', function() {
  return this.get('departuredates').map((departuredate) => {
    // compute `endDate` using moment.js or something
    // (just adding up the date and number will not work).
    const endDate = departuredate.get('value') + this.get('duration');

    return `${departuredate.get('value')} - ${endDate}`;
  }).join(', ');
})
```

Does this make sense?